# Cannot read property 'NullLogger' of undefined

Tags: angular, angular2-components, angular2-cli

I am using this error when i am trying to create a new project.

```
Cannot read property 'NullLogger' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'NullLogger' of undefined
```

I am using **cli version 1.4.4** and i don't want to update my cli version.

Does anyone know about this?

Comment: What is the problem if you upgrade your cli version?

Comment: I too have the same problem . my **CLI version 1.4.6**. I am trying to create a new project using `ng new my-app`. But it's throwing the above error. and I can't change version as my existing project is on **1.4.6**.

Comment: i am using CLI version 1.4.4

Comment: i don't want to upgrade CLI version i want to use only CLI version 1.4.4 only